# SQL Server: How do I check whether records exist for each group in a list of groups?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a TableA:

```
TeamID PersonID
 ...   ...
 1     100
 2     101
 2     105
 2     444
 3     501
 ...   ...
```

Also TableB

```
PersonID CourseID
...      ...
444      c103
444      c2048
101      c3214
...      ...
```

How do I write a simple query such that, for example, I can find whether each person in Team 2 has at least one CourseID associated in TableB. The result for my example is:

```
TeamID PersonID HasCourse
 2     101      1
 2     105      0
 2     444      1
```

The shorter the query the better, ideally not using loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just use `case exists`:

```
select a.*,
       (case when exists (select 1 from b where b.personid = a.personid)
             then 1 else 0
        end) as hascourse
from a
where team_id = 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just another method.

```
select a.TeamID, a.PersonID,
 iif(count(b.CourseID)>0,1,0) as HasCourse
from TableA a
left join TableB b on b.PersonID = a.PersonID
where a.TeamID = 2
group by a.TeamID, a.PersonID;
```